# How can I make Multiple recyclerview in bottomsheet (all scrollable) & add button at touchable view of bottomsheet

Tags: android

I have more than two Recyclerview all visible at the same time, but they are not scrollable, I know very well that Bottomsheet allows only one child to scroll, but I have put this question so that I can get some other way around, or some hack to this possible.
And I even want to add a button to the touchable view of Bottomsheet, exactly
at the top of bottomsheet, not at the upper corners/ends (all these things, I have already tried.)
Thanx in advance.

Comment: You can try this custom `BottomSheetBehavior` as it can contain multiple scrollable View: https://github.com/laenger/ViewPagerBottomSheet